# Reading text from textbox and setting it in a dropdown menu in html #html #javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an option in `dropdown` list in a `html form`. The option will be read from a `textbox` then it will be added in a `dropdown` list. I am new to `javascript`. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function addval()
{
alert ("script ee");
var x=document.getElementById("myselect");
var y=document.getElementById("mtxt");
x.Add(y);
alert ("inserted in dropdown");
}
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
  <select id="myselect" name="select">

    <option>op1</option>
    <option>op2</option>
    <option>op3</option>
    <option>op4</option>

  </select>

    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mtxt">
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addval()">


 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Add` method in the [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) class.

You must create the element `<option>` manually:

```
function addval()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
  var y = document.getElementById("mtxt");

  var newOpt = document.createElement('option');
  newOpt.textContent = y.value;
  x.appendChild(newOpt);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function addval()
    {
      var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
      var y = document.getElementById("mtxt");
    
      var newOpt = document.createElement('option');
      newOpt.textContent = y.value;
      x.appendChild(newOpt);
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
  <select id="myselect" name="select">

    <option>op1</option>
    <option>op2</option>
    <option>op3</option>
    <option>op4</option>

  </select>

    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mtxt">
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addval()">


 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @WaqasAhmed if my answer was useful to you, please, click on the arrow to upvote it, and on the `V` to mark it as the accepted answer :)